# dynamically determine the type of integer based on the system (c++)

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

I am writing a program to store data to a file on the unit of every 32 bits (i.e. 4 bytes at a time). I wrote the code in 64-bit windows system but the compiler I used is 32 bits (mingw32). In the current system, the size of int an long are the same, 32 bits (4bytes). I am current porting the code to other systems by recompiling with g++ (without changing the code). However, I found that the size of int or long are different and depending on the system. Is that any way (like using a macro in the header file) to determine the size of an integer so to decide if int or long should be used as the data type in the code? I have to recompile the code in 4 different type of system, it is really a headache if I modify the code to have 4 different copies for each system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do is use the standard types like `int32_t`.  This type is always 32 bits.  I currently use these types in a portable database (berkeley db) for cross-system compatibility.

See [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html) for all of them.

Include stdint.h to get these definitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem with a canonical solution provided by C99.

**[The `<stdint.h>` header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html)** defines a set of types that provide integers of specific sizes, fastest sizes, and minimum sizes. It's quite useful when solving exactly your problem.

It's a good thing you are using mingw32, because unfortunately, the last time I checked Microsoft didn't provide stdint.h with their API. If anyone does need this for Windows, there is an open-source version, see: **http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/**

Answer (score 2):

You can use sizeof(int) to determine the size of the integer.

If you need a specific size you should use int32_t (or int64_t) from stdint.h

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach to the problem is to not use `int`, `long long`, etc, but instead platform independent type aliases: `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, etc.

They are defined in `<stdint.h>`