# Forcing types to a specific size

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been learning C++ and one thing that I'm not really comfortable with is the fact that datatype sizes are not consistent.  Depending on what system something is deployed on an int could be 16 bits or 32 bits, etc.

So I was thinking it might be a good idea to make my own header file with data types like byte, word, etc. that are defined to be a specific size and will maintain that size on any platform.

Two questions.  First is this a good idea?  Or is it going to create other problems I'm not aware of?  Second, how do you define a type as being, say, 8 bits?  I can't just say #define BYTE char, cause char would vary across platforms.

Comment: Take a look at `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`. int8_t uint8_t.. are defined in there

Comment: @Legion - When you program on an 8-bit or 16-bit system, it is a great *advantage* that `int` isn't 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: Although keep in mind that `int` has a guaranteed minimum size of 16 bits.

Comment: I should have defined my question better.  I was thinking in terms of reading/writing to files and buffers and needing to put precisely an 8 bit value here or a 32 bit value there.  I was concerned that if I used, for example char to signify an 8 bit byte, that if I ported my code to another system, perhaps it would break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, other people have noticed this same problem. In C99 and C++11 (so set your compiler to compatibility with one of those two modes, there should be a switch in your compiler settings), they added the header stdint.h (for C) and cstdint (for C++). If you `#include <cstdint>`, you get the types int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, and the same prefixed with a u for unsigned versions. If your platform supports those types, they will be defined in the header, along with several others.

If your compiler does not yet support that standard (or you are forced by reasons out of your control to remain on C++03), then there is also [Boost](http://www.boost.org/boost/cstdint.hpp).

However, you should only use this if you care exactly about the size of the type. `int` and `unsigned` are fine for throw-away variables in most cases. `size_t` should be used for indexing `std::vector`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, use the already defined stuff in stdint.h. See [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html) for more details.  Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165559/dynamically-determine-the-type-of-interger-based-on-the-system-c/10165584#10165584).

Example:
int32_t is always 32 bits.

Comment: Is there something similar that defines floats as well?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I don't think it's possible to do so even.

Comment: See http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/fpmath/ for more information on why you can't have cross-platform floats

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out if you really care what sizes things are.  If you are using an int to count the number of lines in a file, do you really care if it's 32-bit or 64?  You need BYTE, WORD, etc if you are working with packed binary data, but generally not for any other reason.  So you may be worrying over something that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Many libraries have their own .h with a lots of typedef to have constant size types. This is useful when making portable code, and avoid relying on the headers of the platform you are currently working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make sure the builtin data types have a minimum size you can use std::numeric_limits in the header  to check.

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::digits
```

will give you, for example, the number of bits of an int without the sign bit. And

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

will give you the max value.